# Is it possible to specify more than one expected-response-type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

**tl;dr**

I have a REST service that responds with an XML body. I want to unmarshall the response using an HTTP Message Converter. However, the XML returned from the service does not always map to a single Java type. How do I configure a HTTP outbound gateway to expect more than one response type?

---

I am using

- Java 1.6
- Spring Integration 3.0.0.RELEASE
- Spring Integration HTTP 3.0.0.RELEASE
- Spring OXM 4.0.1.RELEASE

I am trying to setup an `int-http:outbound-gateway` that calls a REST service. The REST service responds with 'text/xml'. I want to be able to use a [MarshallingHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-marhsalling-converter) to marshall the response to a Java Object.

The REST service can respond with either a 'successful' XML response or an 'error' XML response. For example, it may return:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<success>
    <yay>You're call was successful, here is the information you wanted.</yay>
    <information>very important stuff</information>
</success>
```

or it may return:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<failure>
    <boo>You're call was unsuccessful, go in the corner and cry.</boo>
    <error>very important error code</error>
</failure>
```

Therefore, I need to have 2 Java Objects setup to map these different responses to. So I have created

Success.java:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "success")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Success{

    private String yay;
    private String information;

    @XmlElement(name = "yay")
    public String getYay() {
        return yay;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "information")
    public String getInformation() {
        return information;
    }
    //setters omitted for brevity.
}
```

Failure.java:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "failure")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Failure{

    private String boo;
    private String information;

    @XmlElement(name = "boo")
    public String getBoo() {
        return boo;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "error")
    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }
    //setters omitted for brevity.
}
```

Now, in order to setup the outbound Gateway I have a `RestTemplate` configured with a `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`. On the `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`, I inject an OXM unmarshaller that has bound the Success and Failure objects:

```xml
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="myRestMarshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.example.Success" />
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.example.Failure" />
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
```

The problem is that when I try to set up my `int-http:outbound-gateway`, I can only put one of `com.example.Success` or `com.example.Failure` into the `expected-response-type` attribute. If I choose to use `Success`, it will throw an exception if the REST service responds with a `Failure` and vice-versa.

```xml
<int-http:outbound-gateway
    id="myRestServiceGateway"
    url-expression="'http://localhost:8855/webapp/ws/testId/{testId}'"
    http-method="GET" 
    request-channel="restRequest"
    reply-channel="restResponse" 
    rest-template="restTemplate"
    expected-response-type="com.example.Success">

    <int-http:uri-variable name="testId" expression="payload"/>

</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

How do I tell the outbound gateway that the response type could be `com.example.Success` **or** `com.example.Failure`?

Comment: better to design the service to return a symmetrical response for success and failure cases. `<response><type>success/failure</type><information>...</information></response>`

Comment: @AhsanShah agreed that would be nice but I don't have control over the service, I just have to use it. In my opinion, the `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` should consider any of the marshaller's bound classes to be an expected response type instead of having to specify just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't specify several `expected-response-type` since it is a part of `RestTemplate`
   to convert response via `ResponseExtractor`.
2. It is true that `RestTemplate` uses `HttpMessageConverter` to convert the response to the appropriate Java object.
3. Since you expect XML as response and want to convert it to the POJO, using `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` is the right way to go.

So how can you handle your requirement to convert both the success and failure responses?

We can't configure several types for the `RestTemplate`, but we can do it for `JaxbMarshaller`. There is a trick to deceive the `RestTemplate` and `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`.

You can create a super-class for both `Success` and `Failure` and configure it as the `expected-response-type`. Add it as another `class-to-be-bound` for `JaxbMarshaller` in addition to `Success` and `Failure`.

And don't forget to mark the new super-class with `@XmlRootElement`, because `JaxbMarshaller` uses `checkForXmlRootElement = true` by default.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edits, I think I still captured your meaning. So if I were to go this route and create a common super-class, could I put anything in the `@XmlRootElement(name="")`?  For example: `@XmlRootElement(name="null")`. Or can I leave the name out entirely?

Comment: You can don't do that, but then you should switch of `checkForXmlRootElement` for the `Jaxb2Marshaller` bean. And I'm not sure that `<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>` has that option. Or just configure `@XmlRootElement`. That superclass can be empty: it is needed just only to deceive `Jaxb2Marshaller#supports`. The `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` just checks if the result of unmarshalling is an instance of expected class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did confirm that this method would work. However, I decided to use another approach. Check out my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

[Artem Bilan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23526322/953327) answers my question as asked. However, I ended up using another method to accomplish my goal.

I set up my outbound gateway to receive the xml as a String and I did not use `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`. Instead I placed my outbound gateway in a chain where the gateway is the first endpoint and an unmarshalling transformer is the second endpoint. So my configuration looks like this:

```xml
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="myRestMarshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.example.Success" />
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.example.Failure" />
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

<int:chain input-channel="restRequest" output-channel="restResponse">
    <int-http:outbound-gateway
        id="myRestServiceGateway"
        url-expression="'http://localhost:8855/webapp/ws/testId/{testId}'"
        http-method="GET" 
        rest-template="restTemplate"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String">

        <int-http:uri-variable name="testId" expression="payload"/>

    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

    <int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer unmarshaller="myRestMarshaller"/>
</int:chain>
```

I like this method better because I think it provides a little more separation of concerns. Now the gateway is only concerned with communicating with the HTTP service and the marshaller is concerned with translating the response.

I also don't need to introduce an extra class to my model that will never be used.

Comment: Great! It is the second solution but from other side. I orginally answered to your question about two classes. However I like your desicion and I should be more general in the future to think how to answer more thoroughly. Thanks